# Remove top padding from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I made a AlertDialog and there's this nasty top padding on my AlertDialog for some reason using the default Android lollipop+ theme and I can't figure out how to edit it/get rid of it.

Here's the code that I use to produce the AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            } else {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            }
            builder.setTitle("Found corrupted files")
                    .setMessage("We've found " + count + " images that are either missing or " +
                            "corrupt. Should we remove these entries from the list?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yeah", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int i) {
                            MainActivity.this.removeCorruptedImages();
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int i) {
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_white_24dp);

            AlertDialog al = builder.create();
            al.show();
```

And it produces this:
[image]

I want to get rid of that padding/blank space above the title.

Comment: is it the same if you don't specify the theme and use the same Builder(Context) constructor for all versions?

Comment: no but instead it takes on a completely white background with black text (which looks hideous with the apps theme). i still wouldn't know where to go to actually make my own dialog resource though. (turns out you can only set your own dialog view in API 21 or greater, though this app is targetting api 16). I'm fine with it looking bad on pre lollipop, it's just post-lollipop i want to get rid of that massive padding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this line before showing your AlertDialog

`AlertDialog al = builder.create();
 al.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 al.show();`

Comment: this worked, thank you. just curious though, what's it actually removing here? i imagine not the alertdialog title since that still remains? what window feature actually is this

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to set view spacing like this :

`a1.setView(View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom)`

Comment: what would I be setting the view to, in this case? using this with al.getListView(); for the view argument, this seems to do nothing, no matter what values i use for all the other arguments, or whether its' done before, or after the alertdialog is created

Comment: @343N The view to show in the content area of the dialog, you can start with `0` space for other argument, i suppose before invoke `show` method.

Comment: but i'm not showing a (custom) view for them, i'm using the default AlertDialog view, and it'd be much easier for me to just retrieve and use that (if possible) rather than make my own

Comment: tried that, didn't work either. Meikekem's solution worked, but thanks for your help regardless!